# How to setup Development environment in Netbeans Windows OPENGL.?

Tags: windows, opengl, glsl

I am trying to develop one sample opengl 3D application using Netbeans with MingW.

1. How to compile opengl sample code in netbeans.?
2. what is shader language(GLSL) in opengl.?
3. Can i run GLSL code in netbeans.?

Comment: [This page](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-1-opening-a-window/) has enough data to get you started; it walks you through step-by-step on how to set up OpenGL development on Windows, Linux and Mac.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How to compile opengl sample code in netbeans?

Just like any other program as well. Only addition is, that you must configure the OpenGL API interface library as another dependency. Since you didn't specify which language you use I can not tell you how it's named. For regular Windows programs written in C or C++ the name is `opengl32.lib` and it's part of the standard compiler environment.

Netbeans is a Java IDE, so I suppose you want Java. Then the de-facto standard binding library would be LWJGL.

> 2. what is shader language(GLSL) in opengl?

The programming language in which shaders are written. Shaders are programs that are executed by the GPU for every primitive and pixel drawn to the framebuffer. GLSL compilation is done by the OpenGL driver, your program just passes the GLSL code into a function of OpenGL, namely `glShaderSource`

> 3. Can i run GLSL code in netbeans?

No because GLSL is not a regular programming language that produces executables you'd "run" in the classical sense.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my system had Intel HD graphics driver,But no Opengl driver. if I install Opengl Driver in my system(Windows) ,Is possible to compile shader language(GLSL) in netbeans.?

Comment: @balajichinna: You don't compile GLSL into some kind of binary. You ship the GLSL source code with your program. When the program gets run (on the target computer) the source code is handed over to the OpenGL driver there and the driver compiles it. GLSL is not like Java or C which you can compile "offline" and then ship the binary.

Comment: Thanks sir.I understood. Opengl driver only understand shaders language. Is correct sir..? Once i install Opengl driver,then only i will create opengl with shader code. Is it correct.?